# How to express that instances with equal values of different classes are instances from an other class?

Tags: owl, semantic-web, protege, description-logic

I have four classes: A, B, C and S. Class A has inferred instances i1 and i2 which are based on a numerial value condition (in Equivalent To). Class B has inferred instances i3 and i4 which are based on a numerial value condition (in Equivalent To). A and B are subclasses of S.

Each instance has an xsd:dateTime value.

I would like to model that each instance from A and B which have an equal xsd:dateTime value are also instances (inferred) from class C. How do I model such an expression with Protege?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use SWRL for that. In the SWRL tab of Protege add the following rule:

```
A(?a) ^ B(?b) ^ hasDateTime(?a, ?aDateTime) ^ hasDateTime(?b, ?bDateTime) ^ 
   swrlb:equal(?aDateTime, ?bDateTime) -> C(?a) ^ C(?b)
```

assuming you have a `hasDateTime` data property.

Comment: Is this also possible with general class axioms?

Comment: Yes if you have A \sqsubseteq B as an axiom in your ontology it will work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you please give me a complete solution or example how to implement my question? I am a beginner ... Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can you please give me a complete solution or example how to implement concept inclusion for solving such a problem? I am a beginner ... thanks a lot in advance! How do I express concept inclusion in Protege?

Comment: So you don't have an ontology as yet ? A, B, C and S are not classes in your ontology? If not, what kind of classes are talking about here then?